# Multiple if condition in java " if value exists in a list "

Tags: java, if-statement

Is there another alternative to do this in java instead of listing values one by one ?

```
if ( x.equals("a") || x.equals("b") || x.equals("c") || x.equals("d") || x.equals("e") ){}
```

for example x exists in this list (a,b,c,d,e)

Comment: `if (Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d,", "e").contains(x)) {...}`. But from performance perspective it is less efficient.

Comment: `Set.of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e").contains(x)`. For added efficiency create the set only once and hang on to it somewhere (a `static final` variable, for example).